# findViewById of TextSwitcher returns null after replacing fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception

I've tried almost everything I found on internet.

I cleaned the project, tried to call in view's context, many other things but to no avail.

Here's my code in activity

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
    ft.replace(R.id.container, new displayFragment() );
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    // Start the animated transition.
    ft.commit();

    TextSwitcher textSwitcher = (TextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.tswitch);
    if(textSwitcher == null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Pointer is null",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

displayFragment class

```
public class displayFragment extends Fragment{

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display, container, false);
    }
```

fragment_display.xml

```
<TextSwitcher 
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/tswitch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fragment is not guaranteed to be available as soon as you call `ft.commit()`.

Try accessing your textSwitcher from the `onCreateView()` method of your fragment, rather than directly from the activity.

Example:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display, container, false);

        TextSwitcher textSwitcher = (TextSwitcher) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tswitch);
        //Do stuff with textSwitcher

        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide any reference for your answer?